# How to find the analytical expression of function f [x] for such a composite function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

The known analytical formula for composite functions is:

```
f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x
```

The analytical formula for f [x] cannot be obtained through this method：

```
In[62]:= Clear["Global`*"]
RSolve[{f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x}, f[x], x] // FullSimplify

Out[63]= RSolve[{1/x + x == f[(1 + x)/Sqrt[x]]}, f[x], x]
```

and this method is also cannot

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Simplify /@ (f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x /. 
    Solve[y == Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x], x][[1]]) /. {y -> x, 
  Equal -> Rule}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what **The known analytical formula for composite functions is: f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x** mean?  According to Reduce, `Reduce[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x] == x + 1/x]` is true when x=1 only.  What is `f` role here? I am not reading your question right it seems.

Comment: ```f```F represents the corresponding relationship of the function

Comment: What is the analytical expression required for f [x]. Known conditions are f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x

Comment: Well, according to reduce, if you give me `Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]` and want me to return back `x + 1/x` then only when `x=1` this is possible. I am not sure what you mean by how to represent `f` in this case. Hopefully someone will have an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn1 = f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x;

sol = Solve[y == Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x], x] // Quiet

(* {{x -> 1/2 (-2 + y^2 - y Sqrt[-4 + y^2])}, 
    {x -> 1/2 (-2 + y^2 + y Sqrt[-4 + y^2])}} *)
```

Using first solution,

```
eqn2 = f[y] == Simplify[x + 1/x /. sol[[1]]] /.
  {y -> x, Equal -> Rule}

(* f[x] -> -2 + x^2 *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn1 /. f -> Function[{x}, x^2 - 2] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Using the second solution,

```
eqn3 = f[y] == Simplify[x + 1/x /. sol[[2]]] /.
  {y -> x, Equal -> Rule}

(* f[x] -> -2 + x^2 *)
```

This is identical to the first result.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `f` is invertible:

```
eqn = f[y] == f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x;
Solve[Eliminate[eqn, {x}], f[y]]
```

> InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.
>
> ```
> {{f[y] -> -2 + y^2}}
> ```

Note: The solution `f` is invertible on the implicit domain, which is the range of the argument `Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]` (`Re[y] >= 0`). However, the method works on `Solve[Eliminate[f[y] == f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == 2, {x}], f[y]]`, even though `f[y] -> 2` is not invertible.
The warning arises because `Solve` uses `InverseFunction[f][f[u]]` to extract the argument `u`, which is what you see others (in the OP and other answer) doing by hand.